# apache2 mod_headers not working

Tags: apache, mod-headers

**Question Description:** I want to set my site "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", so I set it in apache's config (almost anywhere), but it's not working. I also set other headers for testing, but it's still not working too.

**Apache version:** 2.2.22

**Apache modules:** http://www.anwcl.com/test/show_modules.php

**My target url:**

```
http://www.anwcl.com/test/test_only_div.html
```

**And it's linked to my local file:**

```
e:\wamp\www\test\test_only_div.html
```

---

### **And here's my apache's configurations:**

**E:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf**

```
...
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
...
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
...
```

**E:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header echo ^TS
    Header add MyHeader "Hello Joe. It took %D microseconds for Apache to serve this request."
    ServerAdmin xxx@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "E:/wamp/www/"
    ServerName www.anwcl.com
    ErrorLog "logs/xxx.log"
    CustomLog "logs/xxx.log" common
    <Directory "E:/wamp/www/">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**E:\wamp\www\.htaccess**

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

**E:\wamp\www\test\.htaccess**

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

---

### **And here's Wireshark's caps, there are no expected headers :**

```
http://www.anwcl.com/question/apache-mod-headers-not-working.jpg
http://www.anwcl.com/question/apache-mod-headers-not-working-304.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

I also ran into this issue and fixed it when I realized I was modifying the wrong Virtual-host in my config file found here: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`.

I was modifying the default VirtualHost config when I was using one with a different port.

```
<VirtualHost *:6000>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also ran into the error Dylan Maxey described and got around it by disabling the cache in the browser inspector: 
[image: Disabling cache in Chromium based browser]
Here is also a link to a site I found helpful:
https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: Upvote for mentioning about "Disable cache". "Disable cache" solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Check output of `php_info()` to see if mod_headers is loaded from your apache webserver.

Comment: Yea, it is loaded. but still the actual header mentioned on the question is not added.

Answer (score 0):

The changes could have possibly taken place and you aren't seeing the changes within your browser. This is especially typical if you're serving static files like the images you're trying to alter the headers of.

You can even have chrome disable cache while viewing the page with the Javascript console open and still not see the changes take effect.

What you'll want to look for is the response code. If it's a 304, the server has recognized that your browser already has a valid representation of the requested file, and will serve that file. If it does, you will not see the headers you've added after your browser initially downloaded that page.

To see if this is the case, change the url to `http://myexample.com/myimage.jpg?t=1`, or any other random query parameter and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, adding the `Header set "key" "value"` did not work.  I had to use `RequestHeader set "key" "value"` for the `ProxyPass` to send the header.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName myserver.com
  ServerAlias www.myserver.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" "https"
  #
  # Setup SSL
  #
  # SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile location-to-certificate.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile location-to-private.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile location-to-ca_bundle.crt
</VirtualHost>
```